# How to add application shortcuts to Oracle Linux 7 launcher panel

Tags: linux, oracle, shortcut, launcher

On Oracle Linux 5.0, 6.5, I can drag and drop an application menu item to application launcher panel. So I can start an application by clicking icon from the launcher panel. But under Oracle Linux 7, I was not able to do so.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

If you select help under Documentation in the Applications folder and search for favorites you'll get the following answer:

To add an application to the dash for easy access:

1. Click the Applications menu at the top left of the screen and choose the Activities Overview item from the menu.
2. Click the grid button in the dash and find the application you want to add.
3. Right-click the application icon and select Add to Favorites.

Alternatively, you can click-and-drag the icon into the dash.

To remove an application icon from the dash, right-click the application icon and select Remove from Favorites.

Comment: I also just installed OEL 7 and I am hitting the same brick wall of the Gnome 3 GUI. I also wanted to add shortcuts on the top bar, like I used to do with OEL 6. But that is simply no longer possible. :-(. I also can't find a way to put shortcuts on the desktop :-( :-(

Answer (score 0):

On Oracle Linux 7.x

Install GNOME Shell Extension [TaskBar](https://github.com/zpydr/gnome-shell-extension-taskbar) 
Or install it directly from the plug-ins web page [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/584/taskbar/).

Here is a nice picture:
[image]

**To modify your application menu:**

Install alacarte Menu Editor for Gnome 3.
From a terminal run the following commands.

> sudo yum install -y alacarte

Run the alacarte Menu editor

> alacarte &

To learn more about using alacarte watch this video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SC6WOD_sY9E). It is in German, but you can set the subtitle to your language.

Comment: That's nice, but doesn't really answer the question. It changes menus, but not the shortcuts on the screen top panel.

Comment: In that case I suggest using the popular Gnome3 add-on dash to dock https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/